# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word cannot return complete email address

Tags: c#

I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to read texts in a Word document and return every word in the file. In the Word document, there is an email address and unfortunately I don't get complete email address returned to me. For example: the email address is abc@xyz.com but I get (1)abc (2)@ (3)xyz (4). (5)com.

How to get the complete email address by using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word? Thanks.

The code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
                Document document = application.Documents.Open(txtUploadedPathToken.Text);


                // Loop through all words in the document.
                int count = document.Words.Count;


                foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range range in document.Words)
                {

                    string text = range.Text;
                    tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = text, Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left, AutoSize = true });


                }
```

Comment: @SLaks, i have updated my question to include the code

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution. This is by using Content.Text and the .Split as the code below.

```
string doctexts = document.Content.Text;

string[] docwords = doctexts.Split(' ');
```